# Add data to existing control

Tags: php

I have a dropdownbox with pipe dimensions that is populated at start of the application.

I want this to dynamically change when i choose pipe type in another dropdownbox. I've manage to make ajax feature where a html table is plotted with all dimensions depending on what pipe is choosen. So I just want to embedd this feature in the same file.

The code below creates a new dropdownbox with dimensions. But I already have one (which have id=dimensions).

How do I populate the existing one and not creating a new one?

```
echo "<select id='dimensions'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   echo "<option value='" . $row['nominalsize'] ."'>" . 
    $row['nominalsize'] ."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Gah! When you google "php tutorial" you assume the result is up to date. But no. Back to square one then. Thx for info.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I populate the existing one and not creating a new one?

This is quick'n'dirty but should do it: Before you send the AJAX request, remove the existing `<select id='dimensions'>` from the DOM. Then you can safely insert it later on.

To keep the amount of time short, you can also remove it before inserting it. So at the time you get the AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a database tables with the size values defined in your own webpage usage this:

```
<?php 
// Assume that $nominalsize already exists with real value 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE nominalsize='$nominalsize'"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) 
{ 
  // There is already a row with the specified $nominalsize
} 
else 
{ 
  // Not exist, then ... INSERT
}
```

if not and you like retrive information from another page you need CURL or DOM,
and extract tags.

Answer (score 0):

for populate a control after the page is loaded you need some technique like AJAX:

this is a basic workflow:

1. create a response (HTML o AJAX) with the info of the
2. in the page call HTTP Request from javascript (i recommend jQuery for this task)
3. in the callback of the request build the

Example

Options.php

```
<?php
// http://localhost/options.php
// /var/www/options.php
$options = array(
   1 => 'Cat',
   2 => 'Dog'
);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

return json_enconde($options);
```

Script.js

```
// script.js in your page
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $select = $('#id-select);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/options.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, e) { 
          $select.append($('<option value=' + i + '>' + e + '</option>'));
       });
    }
  });
});
```

the previous only are samples but you can figure an idea